# Going through columns and setting a range with "Do while" loop in Vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, do-while

I have a time series range of data with dates on column A and prices in column B.

This data has "N/A" (a string, not an error) in the first 200 rows (this number is not exact and changes each time I run the file, so I cannot reference it directly).

To be able to graph from a range that does not have the "N/A", I am using a "Do While" loop to go through rows until it is not equal to "N/A", and then setting the range.

**Problem:** For some reason, my "i" counter is not summing. The loop starts then ends with i = 1, where it should be i = row number from the last "N/A".

**The relevant part of the code is:**

```
i = 1
If SourceWorksheet = "Ret" Or SourceWorksheet = "Vol" Then

    Do While w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Cells(i, 2) = "N/A"

        i = i + 1     '****Problem IS HERE, IT IS NOT SUMMING TO i

    Loop

    Set RetRange = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(xlLastCell))

Else

    Set RetRange = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).UsedRange

End If
```

**Obs 1:** In this case I set i = 1, but I already tried not assigning a value for it prior but got an error.

**Obs 2:** Since this is a function that receive arguments from a sub, the SourceWorksheet is an argument that will be input by the user.

Any ideas on what is wrong with this code?

Comment: @YowE3K my cells indeed have the string  `"=N/A"`, since they come from another code that puts that string there. It is not an error, it is just an indication that there is not enough data available.

Comment: @YowE3K Indeed you are right. I just did it.

Comment: My comment was wrong, the code indeed have that #. But even so, I already tried changing that to "Not Available" to avoid the #N/A problem, but it still does not work.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I am just going to change it in the code to avoid more confusion. Regarding the Set, also, another good point. I did it in the second part of the if, but forgot it in the first.

Comment: @DGMS89 - Is the a `on Error Resume Next` in the code before the snipped part? I'm asking because i have lunched your code and got the `Type Mismatch` error and had to change  `...Cells(i, 2)` to `...Cells(i, 2).Text` to make it work.

Comment: In the while condition you should use this: `w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Cells(i, 2).Value = "N/A"`. It could be possible, that you have a formula in the cell, than this will always be `False`

Comment: @YowE3K No, it is just ignoring the part inside the loop entirely for some reason.  And indeed, for the range part you are again correct.

Comment: @Wujaszkun There is no error break, and no error in the code as it is. It just reads the first loop line and automatically jumps to the range line. I already tried it with Text, Values, Formulas, it continues to ignore the loop.

Comment: @YowE3K That is it. I just had to set i to 3 and it solves the problem, such stupidity of mine. Thanks for the help. 
Now I am getting an error in the range, says the specified dimension is not valid. But since this is not part of the original post it is irrelevant., please write an answer for the loop part so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a lot of other issues that we had already solved, your loop will fail if cell B1 does not contain "N/A" (e.g. due to headings).

Try this revised code:

```
With w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet)
    If SourceWorksheet = "Ret" Or SourceWorksheet = "Vol" Then
        i = 2 ' or i=3, whatever row contains your first item of data
        Do While .Cells(i, 2).Value = "N/A"
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        Set RetRange = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

    Else

        Set RetRange = .UsedRange

    End If
End With
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I completely forgot about the SpecialCells for the second part.

Comment: @DGMS89 - You also left out the `CellType` portion of the constant's name.  And you weren't qualifying the `Cells` with a reference to the sheet, which meant they would have been referring to the active sheet, and therefore probably crashing when trying to use them as the bounds of a range on the `SourceWorksheet` sheet.  You were definitely having an off day today!

Comment: @DGMS89 Actually, it looks like `xlLastCell` does actually work - even though `xlCellTypeLastCell` is the "correct" constant shown by Intellisense.  `xlLastCell` is a constant in `Excel.Constants` (with a value of 11) and `xlCellTypeLastCell` is a constant in `Excel.XlCellType` (also with a value of 11).